# "if you've got to" meaning in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, harry-potter

> Hedwig's large, round, amber eyes gazed at him reproachfully over the dead frog clamped in her beak.
>
> ‘Come here,’ said Harry, picking up the three small rolls of parchment
>   and a leather thong and tying the scrolls to her scaly leg. ‘Take
>   these straight to Sirius, Ron and Hermione and don't come back here
>   without good long replies. Keep pecking them till they've written
>   decent-length answers **if you've got to**. Understand?’
>
> <sub>*Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix*</sub>

I guess "*if you've got to*" here probably means *if you have any chance* or *if necessary*. But I have no confidence at all. What does it mean here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It cannot be "if you get the chance", as in **if you get to (do it)**.

> I'm going to visit the Tower of London, *if I get to go* to England on business.
>
> I want to visit the Tower of London some day. I hope I get to [visit it].

Why? The tense is all wrong for that meaning.  Harry is telling the owl what is *expected* of it. For that future aspect the simple present would be used when the meaning is *if you have the opportunity*.  But here the tense is not simple present, **get**.

When there is a future context with **have got to**, the meaning will be "need to, must".

Answer (score 1):

It's the second of your two possibilities: *if necessary*.

> I'm on a desert island and the only thing I can see to eat is bugs. I'll eat them *if I have to*.

If that's the only choice or action available (in this case to survive), then so be it.

In other words, if Sirius, Ron, and Hermione won't write long replies *unless* Hedwig pecks at them, then that's what she should do.